# Renamed a page and changed the slug, now its gone

Tags: wordpress

The title says it. I renamed a page in wordpress along with the permalink (the slug also changed) and now I can't find it on my site.

The menu updated along with my changes, but the page content isn't there when I click on it.

[Here's the offending page](http://loganyoung.za.net/portfolio/)

If anyone can tell me what I did wrong and particularly how to fix it, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if I just delete my .htaccess file and let WP rewrite it... (assuming it does that)

Comment: Well that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a conflict with a portfolio feature in my theme (Bello by WeGraphics)... I renamed the permalink and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Try regenerating permalinks - editing permalink settings triggers that regeneration.
Also, if you have any kind of cache plugin running, purge it's data too.

Comment: It worked with the default setting, not with post-name setting